# When you die, what contributes to your "Score"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When you die, 3 things happen.

1. You swear
2. A message appears in the chat log describing how you died
3. A "You died" screen appears, with the options to quit or respawn, and a "Score".

What contributes to this score?

Comment: Upboat for #1 in the list

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Score is determined solely by the amount of experience you've collected since your last death. It is *not* how much experience you have when you die - experience you've spent still counts. For example, if you collect 50 experience, then spend 25 of it, your score is 50, not 25.

Comment: Is this based on XP levels or orbs?

Comment: At a guess, neither. Orbs can have varying amounts of experience (1-1000 according to [the wiki page](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Experience#Experience_orbs)); the total of this amount is probably what's used, rather than basing it on levels or number of orbs picked up.

Comment: It's based on the same score you use with command blocks. So an orb with (1-1000) from the comment above will give you 1 to 1000 acordingly